# TypeError: gapi.auth2.grantOfflineAccess is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am initializing `gapi.auth2` in my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content= "817677528939-dss5sreclldv1inb26tb3tueac98d24r.apps.googleusercontent.com">

        <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
        <script>
            function start() {
                console.log('script running')
                gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                        client_id: '817677528939-dss5sreclldv1inb26tb3tueac98d24r.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                        scope: 'profile email'
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>

    <!-- <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">     -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"> -->

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Then in my react app:

At the top of the page: `/* global gapi */`

```
    handleSignIn() {
        console.log(gapi.auth2)
        gapi.auth2.grantOfflineAccess()
    }
```

the `console.log` is printing:

`{init: ƒ, authorize: ƒ, _gt: ƒ, enableDebugLogs: ƒ, getAuthInstance: ƒ, …}`

so it looks like `gapi.auth2` is a function, but I'm getting the error:

`gapi.auth2.grantOfflineAccess is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are not calling `grantOfflineAccess` on the `GoogleAuth` object. To get the `GoogleAuth` object, you need to call `getAuthInstance()` like so:

```
var ga = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

ga.grantOfflineAccess();
```

Make sure you only call `getAuthInstance()` after first calling `gapi.auth2.init()` as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2getauthinstance).

Comment: grantOfflineAccess() returns authorization_code which can be exchanged for refresh_token correct? so why do we need the complex flow https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline? Can you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Missed a step:

looking at the function that was printed I needed to call another function first:

`gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess()`